# Make a event for a mouse button even if application is minimized

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mouseevent

I want to make an application that responds to a mouse button so I done this:

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        MessageBox(
            NULL,
            (LPCWSTR)L"HALLOOOO",
            (LPCWSTR)L"Worked",
            MB_ICONASTERISK | MB_OK | MB_DEFBUTTON2
        );
        break;
```

but the problem is that this only works if the user clicks on the window and I want it to work even with the window minimized
this work even if the application is minimized

```
GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON);
```

but if I put this in a loop if I press it once it will detect 1 million times because it will just check if the key is down and if I add delay using `Sleep(250)` it may work but sometimes it will not detect anything even if the user pressed the key
I want my app to be able to detect if a key is pressed even if it's minimized how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a window, call `SetWindowsHookEx` with `WH_MOUSE_LL`.

The API is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) and the parameters are explained.

```
HHOOK SetWindowsHookExW(
  [in] int       idHook,
  [in] HOOKPROC  lpfn,
  [in] HINSTANCE hmod,
  [in] DWORD     dwThreadId
);
```

The `lpfn` hook procedure can be defined as follows:

```
HWND hmain_window;
HHOOK hhook;
LRESULT CALLBACK mouse_proc(int code, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    if (code == HC_ACTION && lparam) 
    {
        if (wparam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            //MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT* mstruct = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lparam;
            static int i = 0;
            std::wstring str = L"mouse down " + std::to_wstring(i++);
            SetWindowText(hmain_window, str.c_str());
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wparam, lparam);
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int)
{
    ...
    RegisterClassEx(...);
    hmain_window = CreateWindow(...);
    hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouse_proc, hinst, 0);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) 
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, in visual studio default hinst was named hInstance also what if I don't Unhook it?

Comment: You have to free resources when you no longer need it, otherwise you get resource leak. It's same as memory leak but it's worse because Windows resources are more limited. When the program exits then resources and memory are automatically freed. So in this particular example it may not matter, but make it a habit to undo resource requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) with parameter WH_MOUSE_LL or WH_MOUSE.

[This article](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/using-setwindowshookex-for-dll-injection-on-windows/) shows how to install a keyboard hook. You can replace WH_KEYBOARD with WH_MOUSE to install a mouse hook and use [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644988(v=vs.85)) to handle the callback.

Comment: sorry but I'm new to c++ and I can't understand anything about this function I look for a few examples but I don't know what are LRESULT, CALLBACK, WPARAM, LPARAM can I do something with GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON); to make it work for now? and then I can learn win32 API but now I'm just learning c++ it self

Comment: @ali If you cannot verify that an answer solves your problem, don't accept it. The Windows data types are [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types).

Comment: @IInspectable I'm sorry, I searched about the SetWindowsHook and that was what I want but I couldn't get it working (my program stopped the mouse from working properly and my PC was so laggy) thanks for the document I may be able to get it working now

Comment: [This article](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/using-setwindowshookex-for-dll-injection-on-windows/) shows how to install a keyboard hook. You can replace WH_KEYBOARD with WH_MOUSE to install a mouse hook and use [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644988(v=vs.85)) to handle the callback.